# Creating a sparse coo_matrix and updating within a two for-loop structure

Tags: python

In the outer for-loop, I have `k1` as x-coordinate and in the Inner-loop I have `k2` as y-coordinate. The loop is basically for other purpose, which is to create a temp dictionary (for other purpose). So, I cannot remove the loop structure. I am trying to create a coo_matrix where my coordinates are `k1`,`k2` with a value that I calculate in my inner loop.

Here is this brief code of mine:

```
for k1,v1 in s.iteritems():
    xdict[k1] = None
    for k2,v2 in s.iteritems():
        tempdict = {}
        if k2 in xdict.keys():
            continue
        if k1 == k2:
            continue
        tempdict[k1] = v1
        tempdict[k2] = v2
        r = reduce(set.intersection, (set(val) for val in tempdict.values()))
        new_kee = 'C(' + k1 + ',' + k2 + ')'
        ydict[new_kee] = len(r)
```

The input 's' is a dictionary with the following sample keys and values:

```
216 [234]  
1305 [234, 234, 298, 429]  
2961 [241, 264]  
211 [143]  
....
```

The inner loop calculates the intersection of each of the two records without duplication. In my new dictionary, the output of intersection results will be stored such as:

```
c(216,1305) -> 1  
c(216,2961) -> 0  
c(216,211) -> 0  
c(1305,2961) -> 0  
c(1305,211) -> 0  
c(2961,211) -> 0  
...
```

At this point, I want to store the values in a sparse coo_matrix with coordinates as calculated above such as:

- For the coordinates (216,1305) the value 1 is to be stored
- For the coordinates (216,2961) the value 0 is to be stored
  and so on....

I need help in creating a sparse coo_matrix with value `len(r)` in coordinates `(k1,k2)`. I am not sure if I have to create a matrix before all the loop structure with fixed size and then update within loop, or any other way.

Could some-one please help me on this problem ?

Comment: I have no idea what you want help with... Maybe show the input (what `s` is initially) and output you want to achieve.

Comment: Sir,  The input 's' is a dictionary with the following sample keys and values: 216 [234]
1305 [234, 234, 298, 429]
2961 [241, 264]
211 [143]......

Comment: @Gowtham when providing additional information about your question, please be sure to edit your question with the information instead of adding it as a comment.

Comment: Apologies for inconvenience. Just started with stackoverflow. Trying my best to follow the rules. Just updated my question with inputs asked by seniors. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it. Define two functions:

```
def new_matrix(n,m):
    """Create a new matrix of dimensions 'n' by 'm'."""
    return [[0 for col in range(m)] for row in range(n)]

def update_matrix(matrix,row,col,val):
    """Update a matrix at row,col position with the value 'val'."""
    matrix[row][col] = val
```

Update your code as follows:

```
#You need to know the size ahead of time
#Replace row, col with appropriate dimensions
matrix = new_matrix(row,col)

for k1,v1 in s.iteritems():
    xdict[k1] = None
    for k2,v2 in s.iteritems():
        tempdict = {}
        if k2 in xdict.keys():
            continue
        if k1 == k2:
            continue
        tempdict[k1] = v1
        tempdict[k2] = v2
        r = reduce(set.intersection, (set(val) for val in tempdict.values()))
        new_kee = 'C(' + k1 + ',' + k2 + ')'
        ydict[new_kee] = len(r)

        #Update your matrix here:
        update_matrix(matrix,k1,k2,len(r))
```